# Using Bootstrap, how can I add two heading elements in one row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For some reason, I was able to achieve what I wanted earlier in the day, but now when I am trying to re-create my code, it won't replicate.

**I want two header elements, h2 and h3, centered-aligned in one div row, within the jumbotron section.**

***Then*, I want to add bottom-margin to the h3 element to lift it slightly above the h2 element, like in the photo.**

I still have my original code in hand, but even after copynpasting the exact code with the same styling, the h3 element ends up being directly below h2.

I have tried cross-referencing with dev tools, and i found that the only difference is the div row containing the h2 and h3 elements is missing display:flex, but it's still not working.

[what i want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEuLk.jpg)

[what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG2Qh.jpg)

Original Working Code:

```
HTML:
<section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Jumbotron</h2>
      <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

CSS:
.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665956600293-4511bd26ea98?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2787&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 400px;
}

.jumbotron h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  color: ;
}

.jumbotron h3 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: remove class="row"

Comment: i tried, still no luck :( i am beginner, sorry, but i thought bootstrap meant all container classes require a row class underneath?

Comment: now we need to use only basic part, like hierarchy that does job. In this case we don't need "row" class.  H2 and H3 are block elements. So they fall into new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change row class with d-flex like

```
<section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <h2>Jumbotron</h2>
      <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```